# Pass multiple credential files to access GCP services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

In Beam, how can one pass multiple GCP Credential json files to access various GCP services like GCS, BigQuery, PubSub etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You assign the permissions/roles that you need to a service account and use that one.